# Can't get Zebra ZM600 on my network

Tags: networking, printing

I have a new-to-me zebra ZM600 thermal printer that has been reset to factory defaults. I can't get it to pick up a DHCP address when plugged in to wired network, nor does it pick up an address when it's set to wireless. I'm able to plug the printer in via USB to a workstation to configure and print to it that way, but I need to get it connected to the network instead.

EDIT: I should mention that I can configure a static ip address through the windows software when the printer is USB-connected, but whatever static IP settings I set are unreachable regardless of whether it's using wired or wireless networking.

All the Zebra documentation I've been able to find shows that the IP address can be set from the control panel on the printer. However mine doesn't even have those options in the menu, and the item that shows the "ACTIVE PRINTSRVR" shows "UNKNOWN", but this is a read-only item.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, on some zebra the printserver is a add-on you clip, isnt the case for your model ? as maybe a badly clipped network adapter could cause that problem.

Comment: There's a slot for an additional module, but the ethernet port is built-in on the machine I have.

Comment: I did more testing with different cables and plugging directly into a switch. The printer doesn't even pull the port link up at all. The status LED stays dark on both the printer and the switch.